# Chrome for iOS: "Always allow" for Cookies

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, cookies

Safari browser on OSX has a setting 
Privacy & Security -> Block Cookies -> Always Allow

This setting allows to store entries in browser local storage when the page is loaded from the "third party site" e.g. running in an iframe.
This feature allows to pass credentials between different site for some single sign-on solution implementations.

I don't find the same setting in the Chrome for iOS browser, so that the third party "cookies" do not get persisted in the local browser storage in such scenario.

Is there such setting for Chrome on iOS that I am missing?
Is is generally not possible to pass cookies between sites (even running on the same subdomain) in Chrome for iOS browser?

(I've been testing with Chrome for iOS 52.0.2743.84 and iOS 9.3.2)

Answer (score -1):

Go to:  Settings > Show Advanced Settings > Content Settings > Cookies
there you go all the options.

Version:  52.0.2743.116 on Windows 10

Comment: Sorry Casper, I'm interested in iOS browser only.